# evaluating statement cin==(expression)

Tags: c++, return-value, cout, cin

What does the code below intended to do?

```
return cin==(cout<<(f(a)==f(b)?"YES":"NO"));
```

assume f() is a string returning function and a and b are strings as well and function's signature is

```
string f(string a)
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: It basically resolves to `cin == cout`, which is... weird. Unless that's meant to check the status of both streams is either okay or bad.

Comment: @ Frédéric Hamidi I didn't quite follow you. Can you explain a bit more or suggest a useful reference for the same? Thanks!

Comment: Well, `operator <<` returns the stream it operates on, in our case `cout`. So the code ends up comparing `cin` and `cout` for equality. As I don't believe you can compare streams for equality in the first place, I suspect (but that's only conjecture on my part) that `operator void*()` is applied to both streams and the result of that operator (a null pointer if the stream is bad, a non-null pointer if it's good) ends up being compared.

Comment: Then again, I don't think the standard mandates that `operator void*()` must return the same non-null pointer every time, so this can be bound to fail. Hopefully others will shed some light about this.

Comment: Looks like it's from a code-obfuscation contest or something.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer is: it depends on what C++ standard you're compiling against. It boils down to the conversion functions in [`std::basic_ios`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ios/operator_bool)

**C++03**

Here, we have `operator void*() const`, which:

> Returns a null pointer if `fail()` returns `true`, otherwise returns a non-null pointer. This pointer is implicitly convertible to `bool` and may be used in boolean contexts.

Thus, in the expression:

```
cin==(cout<<(f(a)==f(b)?"YES":"NO"));
```

we would print either "YES" or "NO", and the result of the stream output would be `cout` still (in the form of a `std::ostream&`). When we do the equality check, both operands would be implicitly converted to `void*` and so the expression checks to see if both streams failed. This is a particularly obfusticated way of doing:

```
cout << (f(a) == f(b) ? "YES" : "NO");
return cin.fail() && cout.fail();
```

**C++11**

With C++11, the `operator void*() const` is replaced by `explicit operator bool() const`. The `explicit` is key, as it means that the conversion function can only be used explicitly (as in, via a direct cast) or in a boolean context, as in:

```
if (cin) { // calls cin.operator bool()
}
```

Equality is not a boolean context, so in the expression

```
cin == cout
```

that conversion function will not be invoked. As there is no `operator==` defined on `std::basic_ios` (or `std::istream` or `std::ostream`), the expression will simply not compile.

Comment: @lisyarus No, I really meant `&&`. If neither fail, `==` would return `true`, but the original expression would return false as they would be two different non-null pointers.

Comment: But it does compile and produce desired result. I came across it while going through a solution of (http://codeforces.com/problemset/problem/559/B) .The exact solution is the first one on (http://codeforces.com/problemset/status/559/problem/B)

Comment: @GauravJain It does compile... on C++03. It does not compile on C++11.

Comment: @Barry On (http://codeforces.com/problemset/status/559/problem/B) they have compiled it using C++11(written under the lang. column). The solution I am talking about is authored by (http://codeforces.com/profile/Colonelmo)

Comment: @GauravJain The compiler they're using has a bug then, the code should be disallowed.